# Java type for multiple bounds generics

Tags: java

I have classes that implements two interfaces and I need to call methods in both interfaces.

This doesn't compile:

```
List<? extends Vehicle & Fun> list = Arrays.asList(new Car("a"), new Truck("b"), new Car("c"));
```

However, this works (local variable type inference) and the program runs as expected:

```
var list = Arrays.asList(new Car("a"), new Truck("b"), new Car("c"));
```

How do I specify both interfaces for the variable `list`?

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

interface Vehicle {
    public boolean canRun();
    public void getName();
}

interface Fun {
    public boolean isFun();
}

class Car implements Vehicle, Fun {

    protected String name;

    public Car(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canRun() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFun() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void getName() {
        System.out.println("Car: " + name);
    }
}

class Truck implements Vehicle, Fun   {

    protected String name;

    public Truck(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void getName() {
        System.out.println("Truck: " + name);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canRun() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFun() {
        return false;
    }
}

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var list = Arrays.asList(new Car("a"), new Truck("b"), new Car("c"));
        // The following line doesn't compile
        // List<? extends Vehicle & Fun> list = Arrays.asList(new Car("a"), new Truck("b"), new Car("c"));
        list.stream().filter(v -> v.canRun()).filter(v -> v.isFun()).forEach(Vehicle::getName);
    }

}
```

Comment: You simply can't. The generic argument must be of exactly one type.

Comment: But how come the local variable type inference "var list" works? It must have an internal type representation that supports two interfaces.

Comment: @JustWonder `list` undergoes type erase upon compilation, so there no type at runtime. What you are facing is just compiler forcing you to follow JLS.

Comment: It's quite possible that the compiler can infer types that could not be written out.

Comment: I thought that "var" is just a syntax sugar, but looks like it it more than that - it makes something possible that wasn't before.

Comment: @JustWonder there is no magic. `list` is just `List<Object>` in the end. if you don't believe, just do `list.getClass().getTypeParameters()` and use debugger to inspect bounds from type variable (well, there might be easier way to confirm my hypotesis, but at least this confirms that)